# What must be considered for storing strings of different languages in a sql server database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4, character-encoding

### Background:

For various reasons I'm creating a translation table in my sql server 2008 r2. (This question is not about whether that is a correct / good choice)
This table should store translation for languages like english, german, french. Languages like japanese or chinese might follow shortly.

The table is filled/update by a WinForms application and later shown to customers in an ASP.Net WebApplication.

I'm using the Entity Framework 4 with the Models first (creating entities in the designer to create an create script afterwards)

### Now to the question:

How do I ensure the correct encoding for the save and read operations in the WinForms and the ASP.Net applications?  How must the columnTypes in the database look like?

#### EntityFramework Designer

Apparently I can only use "String" as ColumnType in the EntitityDesigner. Chosing "String" in the designer will translate to **nvarchar(max)**. Is that the correct columnType to store strings of different languages?

#### ConnectionString

I guess adding **Charset=utf8;** to the connectionString is also necessary.

#### ASP.Net

Setting **utf-8** as output type in the ASP.Net application seems logic to me.

#### WinForms

Must I set anything else in the WinForms application? Do I need to call some encoding / decoding methods myself? If yes, which one and why?

---

Have I missed something? Do I need to configure something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nvarchar is correct. It stores data in unicode and you do not need to encode/decode anything if you are using utf-8 in your application.